# iphone : problem replacing string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

```
NSString *re = [[sqlArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Question"];
            question = [re stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"√≠" withString:@"'"];

            question = [re stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"√Æ" withString:@"'"];
         question = [re stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"í" withString:@"'"];
        question = [re stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"√¨" withString:@"'"];
        question = [re stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ë" withString:@"'"];
        NSLog(@"question : %@",question);
```

string is still not being replaced, it shows

question : Resident`√≠`s with the longest length of stay are generally those who

as nslog.
what could be wrong?

Comment: hi you are getting this because every time in question you passed re string and at last only "ë" will be replaced.What you have to do is as you get a question string then pass that question string instead of re string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *re = [[sqlArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Question"];
            question = [re stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"√≠" withString:@"'"];

            question = [question stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"√Æ" withString:@"'"];
         question = [question stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"í" withString:@"'"];
        question = [question stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"√¨" withString:@"'"];
        question = [question stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ë" withString:@"'"];
        NSLog(@"question : %@",question);
```

Comment: but in my case it is not replacing the first condition itself

Comment: I just tried the code with the NSString *re = @"Resident√≠s with the longest length of stay are generally those who" and the output is "question : Resident's with the longest length of stay are generally those who".

Answer (score 0):

When you repeatedly set `question = ...`, you're just changing a local variable and not the value of the `Question` key. So finish this off with

```
[[sqlArray objectAtIndex:0] setObject:question forKey:@"Question"];
```

(That's assuming this is an NSDictionary; perhaps you should use `setValue:forKey:` otherwise, but I can't tell without seeing more of your code.)

Also, as joern points out, you should use `question = [question stringBy...` instead of `question = [re stringBy...` after the first replacement.

Comment: i have set value for question and fetching here with `valueforkey`